# Is there any way to add audio responses to qualtrics?

Tags: qualtrics

Qualtrics does not have native capability to record audio responses. Is there any way I can capture audio responses through it. I have tried pipe recorder.
https://blog.addpipe.com/qualitative-research-video-survey-with-qualtrics-and-pipe-video-recorder/
However it does not allow to capture audio responses through iOS

Answer (score 1):

Phonic (https://phonic.ai) does audio capture and integrates with Qualtrics. It believe it works with iOS.